# Custom GitLag Container Registry Image Creation & Reuse

Tags: gitlab

I want to build and add a custom image (**`with ruby, node.js, bower, grunt, jekyll etc.`**) and tag it as 'myimage:1.0'. This image needs to be stored in gitlab **`container registry`** and then used in **`.gitlab-ci.yml`** as **`image: sachin.1.0.0`**. So that my build via gitlab ci will have everything preinstalled like node.js, etc.

Tried enough, How can this be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you do this, you need to configure a gitlab runner which allows you to use `docker build`. You can configure this using the instructions [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) depending on your use case

Next, create a new repo in gitlab, let's call it `sachin-image`.

Inside the root of the git repo, add a `Dockerfile` with installation of everything you need.

Now, into this repo, add a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like so:

```
---
before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN <my-docker-gitlab-registry-url>

stages:
  - build
build_image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t gitlab.example.com/my/dockerimage/repo:latest .
    - docker push gitlab.example/my/dockerimage/repo:latest
  tags:
    - docker_engine
```

At this point, you now have automated docker builds working in gitlab. In order to use this image in future gitlab builds, all you need to use the following image url:

`gitlab.example.com/my/dockerimage/repo:latest`

Comment: It worked principally but writing Dockerfile is to be handled, thanks.